# String.replace() not Replacing Newlines (or Anything, for that matter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble with getting an "editable" block of text working if the text has line breaks in it.

I have two elements, a `div` and a `textarea`.  When the user clicks Edit, I have the following code to populate the textarea:

```
text = $('#div').text();
$('#div').replaceWith('<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>');
$('#textarea').val(text);
```

When the user is finished editing and clicks Save, I have the following:

```
text = $('#textarea').val();
text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />\n");
$('#textarea').replaceWith('<div id="div"></div>');
$('#div').html(text);
```

However, if the div originally has multiple lines in it (with `<br />` tags), if I click edit and then save, all the line breaks disappear.

I've used Firebug to try and get a feel for what's going on, but it looks like the String.replace() line has absolutely no effect, no matter what I do with it.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text.replace()` does not replace the original text. It **returns** the replaced text.

Please do `text = text.replace(...)`.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`String` objects are *immutable*, that is, they cannot be modified.

With that in mind, all "seemingly mutating" `String` methods (such as `replace()`, `substring()`, `charAt()`, etc) return a `new String` and do not modify the object on which the method was invoked on.

So in order for this to work, you need to store the return value of `replace()`, you can even reassign the original variable to the return value:

```
text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />\n");
```

Comment: Handy to know, about the immutable thing.

Answer (score 2):

Reassign the result of replacement back to the original variable:

```
text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />\n");
```

If you are having trouble with a function it's often a good idea to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> **Description**
>
> This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.
>
> ...
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> var re = /apples/gi;
> var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";
> var newstr = str.replace(re, "oranges");
> ```